# does someone know how to fix these errors

Tags: unity, c#

```
(1)Assets\ep 7\BRS_ChangeCircle.cs(1,25): error CS1002: ; expected
(2)Assets\ep 7\BRS_ChangeCircle.cs(6,2): error CS1513: } expected
(3)Assets\ep 7\BRS_ChangeCircle.cs(7,1): error CS1529: A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations
(4)Assets\ep 7\BRS_ChangeCircle.cs(8,1): error CS1529: A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations
(5)Assets\ep 7\BRS_ChangeCircle.cs(157,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

and here is the coding

```
using System.Collections
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class BRS_ChangeCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
 
    int score = 0;
 
    void OnGUI () {
        guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
 
}
 
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public int Segments;
    [Range(0,5000)]
    public float XRadius;
    [Range(0,5000)]
    public float YRadius;  //THIS IS NOT USED - SHOULD BE ELIMINATED

    [Range(10, 100)]
  public int ZoneRadiusFactor = 50; //default to 50%

    [Header("Shrinking Zones")]
  public List<int> ZoneTimes;

    #region Private Members
    private bool Shrinking;  // this can be set to PUBLIC in order to troubleshoot.  It will show a checkbox in the Inspector
    private int countdownPrecall = 10;  //this MIGHT be public, but it should not need to be changed
    private int timeToShrink = 30; //seconds
    private int count = 0;
    private bool newCenterObtained = false;
    private Vector3 centerPoint = new Vector3(0, -100, 0);
    private float distanceToMoveCenter;
    private WorldCircle circle;
    private LineRenderer renderer;
    private GameObject ZoneWall;
    private float [] radii = new float[2];
    private float shrinkRadius;
    private int zoneRadiusIndex = 0;
    private int zoneTimesIndex = 0;
    private float timePassed;
    #endregion

    void Start ()
    {
        renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        radii[0] = XRadius;  radii[1] = YRadius;
        circle = new WorldCircle(ref renderer, Segments, radii);
        ZoneWall = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ZoneWall");

        timePassed = Time.deltaTime;
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        ZoneWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3 ((XRadius * 0.01f), 1, (XRadius * 0.01f));

        if(Shrinking)
        {
            // we need a new center point (that is within the bounds of the current zone)
            if (!newCenterObtained)
            {
              centerPoint = NewCenterPoint(transform.position, XRadius, shrinkRadius);
                distanceToMoveCenter = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, centerPoint); //this is used in the Lerp (below)
                newCenterObtained = (centerPoint != new Vector3(0, -100, 0));
          }

Debug.Log("New Center Point is " + centerPoint);

            // move the center point, over time
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, centerPoint, (distanceToMoveCenter / timeToShrink) * Time.deltaTime );
            // shrink the zone diameter, over time
            XRadius = Mathf.MoveTowards(XRadius, shrinkRadius, (shrinkRadius / timeToShrink) * Time.deltaTime);
            circle.Draw(Segments, XRadius, XRadius);

            // MoveTowards will continue infinitum, so we must test that we have gotten close enough to be DONE
            if (1 > (XRadius - shrinkRadius))
            {
              timePassed = Time.deltaTime;
                Shrinking = false;
                newCenterObtained = false;
            }
        } else {
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime; // increment clock time
        }

        // have we passed the next threshold for time delay?
        if (((int) timePassed)  > ZoneTimes[zoneTimesIndex])
        {
            shrinkRadius = ShrinkCircle((float)(XRadius * (ZoneRadiusFactor * 0.01)))[1];  //use the ZoneRadiusFactor as a percentage
            Shrinking = true;
            timePassed = Time.deltaTime;  //reset the time so other operations are halted.
            NextZoneTime();
        }

        // COUNT DOWN
        if (timePassed > (ZoneTimes[zoneTimesIndex] - countdownPrecall)) {  // we need to begin counting down
            if (ZoneTimes[zoneTimesIndex] - (int) timePassed != count)
            {
                count = Mathf.Clamp(ZoneTimes[zoneTimesIndex] - (int) timePassed, 1, 1000);  // this ensures our value never falls below zero

                //FILL IN APPROPRIATE UI CALLS HERE FOR THE COUNTDOWN
                Debug.Log("Shrinking in " + count + " seconds.");
            }
        }
    }

    // ***********************************
    // PRIVATE (helper) FUNCTIONS
    // ***********************************
    private Vector3 NewCenterPoint(Vector3 currentCenter, float currentRadius, float newRadius)
    {
        Vector3 newPoint = Vector3.zero;

        var totalCountDown = 30000; //prevent endless loop which will kill Unity
        var foundSuitable = false;
        while (!foundSuitable)
        {
             totalCountDown--;
             Vector2 randPoint = Random.insideUnitCircle * (currentRadius * 2.0f);
             newPoint = new Vector3(randPoint.x, 0, randPoint.y);
             foundSuitable = (Vector3.Distance(currentCenter, newPoint) < currentRadius);
             if (totalCountDown < 1)
               return new Vector3(0, -100, 0);  //explicitly define an error has occured.  In this case we did not locate a reasonable point
        }
        return newPoint;
    }

    private int NextZoneTime()
    {
        //if we have exceeded the count, just start over
        if (zoneTimesIndex >= ZoneTimes.Count -1) // Lists are zero-indexed
          zoneTimesIndex = -1;  // the fall-through (below) will increment this

        // next time to wait
        return ZoneTimes[++zoneTimesIndex];
    }

    // This is a general purpose method
    private float[] ShrinkCircle(float amount)
    {
        float newXR = circle.radii[0] - amount;
        float newYR = circle.radii[1] - amount;
        float [] retVal = new float[2];
        retVal[0] = newXR;
        retVal[1] = newYR;
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: try reading the messages. they literally tell what to do

Answer (score 1):

When you have a number of errors in the same sourcecode file, then it's usually a good idea to fix them from top to bottom, because fixing one error might remove or change the errors below it. So I copied your code to a new file in Visual Studio and went through the errors from top to bottom.

---

The first error is very straight forward: A semicolon is expected on line 1, position 25. So just add a semicolon after the very first line:

```
using System.Collections;
```

Funny thing: Visual Studio now displays that line in gray, which tells us that there isn't actually anything in this file which requires this `using`-declaration. So we could actually just as well remove it altogether.

---

Then you are apparently trying to create two `MonoBehaviour`s in one sourcecode file: `BRS_ChangeCircle` and `Score`. This won't work. The C# language *does* allow you to have multiple classes in one sourcecode file, but Unity requires a separate file for each `MonoBehaviour` in order to allow you to assign them to GameObject's. And even if you would want to create a class inlined in another (which you might want to do from time to time, just not with a `MonoBehaviour`), then the `using`-declarations required by the inner class need to be on top of the whole file. So remove this part and put it into a new file `Score.cs`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    int score = 0;

    void OnGUI() {
        guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }

}
```

There is also another problem with this piece of code, and that that there is no variable `guiText` in that script. It is likely supposed to be a `public UnityEngine.UI.Text` or `public TMPro.TextMeshPro`.

---

Next error is this line:

```
public List<int> ZoneTimes;
```

This one is simple, and Visual Studio already provides an auto-correction. You forgot to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the very top of the script. This package is required for the class `List`.

---

Then there are just two errors remaining, which are related to the class `WorldCircle` being unknown. This is not a Unity or C# standard class, so I assume it's another class from your project. So if you have that class in your project, you shouldn't get that error.

---

**Conclusion:** It looks as if you copied a very long script written by someone else to your project, and then you tried to modify it by adding code you saw in some YouTube tutorial without really understanding what you were doing.

It's hard to get anywhere in Unity when you don't have at least a basic understanding of the C# language and how to interpret its error messages. If my impression is correct, then I would really recommend to do [a basic, technology-neutral C# tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/) first.

Comment: thanks that helped

Comment: oh sorry can you put the fixed coding script like in that greyd out thing of this as a answer so i can copy it please beacause im new at creating games and i have zero experience in coding

Comment: @flynn1023 I think you would learn more if you actually tried to understand the reasons for these problems and tried to fix them yourself. I think I gave you pretty detailed instructions, so that shouldn't be very hard. But if you insist: https://pastebin.com/47Vi8A73

Comment: ok i will try                             .

Comment: for some reason it told me to delete the script now i cant use the script and put it on the thing i need it on